# scala pattern matching with regexp lookbehind operator

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract a value from a String using a regexp and pattern matching :

```
val reg = """((?<=a)b)""".r
"ab" match { case reg(x) => x }
```

No matter how I try, it still throws a MatchError. However, if I try the following method :

```
reg.findAllIn("ab").mkString
```

The regex behaves as expected : `res28: String = b`

Of course, I could simply change the regex and add another group :

```
val reg = """(a)(b)""".r
"ab" match { case reg(_,x) => x }
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible to use look ahead/behind operators with pattern matching.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but in a pattern match you [don't get a call](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unapplySeq(s:CharSequence):Option[List[String]]) to [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), as you do in [`Regex.findAllIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@findAllIn(source:CharSequence):scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator), so you have to turn it into an [`UnAnchoredRegex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex) by using [`Regex.unanchored`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unanchored:scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex) (or match everything in the first go):

```
val reg = "((?<=a)b)".r.unanchored
// ".*((?<=a)b)".r would also work
"ab" match { case reg(x) => x }
```

The key entry in the ScalaDoc is:

> This method **attempts to match the entire input by default**; to find the next matching subsequence, use an unanchored Regex.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: `unanchored` doesn't get enough exposure.

Comment: @som-snytt : what do you mean by exposure ?

Comment: As in press, mention, so people know to use it. You wouldn't, coming from java.